# Read-only USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, rufus

Today i installed ISO on my USB through Rufus. At the end of unpacking progress it gave me a crash and now my USB is in read-only mode. I tried all ways on Windows and even something on live Ubuntu. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

In an Ubuntu live session you can use the [MKUSB's "Restore to a standard storage device" feature](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive).

How to install MKUSB (internet connection in the live session required):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

Comment: I got this error, when typed last command: "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: Do a full update/upgrade and then the last command again: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Nope, its still gives me same error.
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mkusb : Depends: pv but it is not installable
         Depends: wmctrl but it is not installable
         Depends: guidus but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: So you need to open Software & Updates and select all the repositories before proceeding.